# Is there any way to control how often google maps updates your location?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, idle-timer

Im developing a version of google maps for a phone application and im trying to figure out how to let the users manually update their locations rather than automatically updating(mainly for battery conservation). I searched through the new google api v3 developer page and I couldnt seem to find anything. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Google knows nothing about your location. There is no pull from them. Any location is given by a push from the device/browser.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways google knows your location.

There's HTML5 location, which is the most accurate.
This is usually the preferred way to get location.

But, as we all know, not everyone wants to do that.
Google still wants to provide a good user experience for those users.

So second way to get location, IP Location.
Ip location is correct approximately 85% of the time, depending on the database you use for it. Some are more accurate. But it usually gets within about 25-50 miles of the user location, whereas html5 location is within just a few miles of your location. I've personally had my location pulled within just a few feet of where I was.

As far as updating, I would imagine google probably updates monthly and caches the location in their system. While location is an important variable in their ads, google also has to be fast and efficient, so it's a good compromise. Unless you're using the maps feature, that already has cached hits built into each area so they can get your location and then serve you content via AJAX through their thousands of cached servers.